# Rotary encoder Grayhill SERIES 26 pinout

Tags: encoder, rotary

I can't figure out how this rotary encoder works. What's the Vcc and GND?

The technical sheet is attached here but it does not say anything about how to wire it

[image]

http://www.grayhill.com/assets/1/7/Mech_Encoder_26.pdf

Comment: the encoder contains 4 switches all connected to one common .. wire same way as 4 pushbuttons

Answer (score 0):

The rotary switch could be called a HEX position 4P16T rotary encoder with negative logic where 0= open cct = all "1's" and the wipers connected to Gnd.